# some detail about Borsuk Lemma

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

this is from Munkres Topology and I'm confused about the extension of $j$ from $A$ to $A\cup C$ by the preceding lemma which is the below:

[image]

according to this lemma $C\cup A \times I$ should be normal but how we know it, what I'm missing?

Comment: $C$ and $A$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, in particular metric spaces, so $(C \cup A) \times I$ is also a metric space and therefore in particular normal.

Comment: and the product of any two metric spaces is normal?

Comment: The product of any two metric spaces is a metric space... and therefore in particular normal, yes.